# Convert bash parameters to variables

Tags: bash

I'd like to let the user override some variables I use in an existing script, and I wondered if there were an easy way to do this in a generic way.
For example my script is:

```
LOG_LEVEL="DEBUG"
echo $LOG_LEVEL
```

Now if I run

```
./myscript.sh LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
```

I'd like the LOG_LEVEL variable to be overriden by the parameter value.
The underlying question is : is it possible to set a variable value from the variable name. The mechanism I'm asking for would require something like this:

```
set(varname, value)
```

Comment: You can try to set `LOG_LEVEL` using the value of a positional parameter (`$1` f.e.) and `DEBUG` as its default value: `LOG_LEVEL=${1:-DEBUG}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could do it the native way.

```
LOG_LEVEL="INFO" ./myscript.sh
```

Would that be sufficient?

Comment: Inside the script, you can set a default like `: ${LOG_LEVEL:=INFO}` which will take effect if no value is passed in the environment.

Comment: It also needs a statement in the script to check if `LOG_LEVEL` is not set and use a default value to set it in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could look for arguments that look like variable assignments and `eval` them:

```
#!/bin/sh

for arg
do
  if printf '%s' "${arg}" |
      grep -q '^[A-Z_]\+='
  then
    IFS='=' read -r var val <<EOF
${arg}
EOF
    eval "${var}=$(printf '%s' "${val}" |
                     sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g;1s/^/'/;\$s/\$/'/")"
  fi
done

printf 'LOG_LEVEL=%s\n' "${LOG_LEVEL:-}"
```

The `grep -q '^[A-Z_]\+='` part is what determines what looks like an assignment. It could be tweaked to be more allowing, e.g. lower-case variable names, or more restrictive, e.g. `^LOG_LEVEL=`.

<sup>The above tries to be clever about special characters in the value, but I can’t guarantee it won’t fail horribly in some strange cases.</sup>

Comment: Seems to do what I need bu Noufal Ibrahim's solutions is more simple.

Comment: @jaudo It sure is. And safer and more allowing too.  I just found it a fun challenge.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to set a variable via a variable name indirectly. `printf -v` is one of them. Try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_LEVEL="DEBUG"
LOG_FILE="/tmp/log.txt"

for arg in "$@"; do
    if [[ "$arg" == *?=?* ]]; then
        varname="${arg%=*}"    # lvalue
        value="${arg#*=}"      # rvalue
        printf -v "$varname" %s "$value"
    fi
done

echo "LOG_LEVEL=$LOG_LEVEL"
echo "LOG_FILE=$LOG_FILE"
```

Then try to invoke: `./thisscript LOG_LEVEL="INFO" LOG_FILE="/dev/null"` or whatever.
Hope this helps.